# Rotate and Flip an image pixel by pixel

Tags: c++

I have the following image, I would like to rotate and flip it so that it fits the full screen resolution.
I'm doing the following conversion, to rotate, but it doesn't work.

[Here is the source image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwfcM.jpg)

```
size_t bpp = Ogre::PixelUtil::getNumElemBytes(source.getFormat());

        const unsigned char *srcData = source.getData();
        unsigned char *dstData = new unsigned char[width * height * bpp];


        size_t srcPitch = source.getRowSpan();
        size_t dstPitch = width * bpp;

        ImageDescriptor sourceImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), bpp);
        ImageDescriptor rotatedTarget(source.getHeight(), source.getWidth(), bpp);  // note width/height swap

        unsigned char *rotated = new unsigned char[source.getHeight() * source.getWidth() * bpp];

        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rotatedTarget.mHeight; ++row) {
            for (std::size_t col = 0; col < rotatedTarget.mWidth; ++col) {
                for (std::size_t chan = 0; chan < rotatedTarget.mChannels; ++chan) {
                    rotated[rotatedTarget.offset(col, row, chan)] =
                    srcData[sourceImage.offset(row, col, chan)];
                }
            }
        }




struct ImageDescriptor {
        std::size_t mWidth;
        std::size_t mHeight;
        std::size_t mChannels;
        ImageDescriptor(std::size_t width, std::size_t height, std::size_t channels)
        {
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
            mChannels = channels;
        }
        std::size_t stride() const { return mWidth * mChannels; }
        const std::size_t offset(std::size_t row, std::size_t col, std::size_t chan) {
            assert(0 <= row && row < mHeight);
            assert(0 <= col && col < mWidth);
            assert(0 <= chan && chan < mChannels);
           // return row*stride() + col*mChannels + chan;
            // or, depending on your coordinate system ...
             return (mHeight - row - 1)*stride() + col*mChannels + chan;
        }
        std::size_t size() const { return mHeight * stride(); }
    };
```

[Here is the result image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgPtI.png)

[Answer Result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzIa6.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: 'but it doesn't work'. You've asked enough times to know that is a useless statement. It doen't work but what exactly goes wrong? What do you see when you run the code?

Comment: @john I attached the result image

Comment: Looks OK to me, the result image has rotated 90 degrees, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @john I want to flip the image vertically in the Y axis, so that I have correct image view of the router

Comment: Looking at the picture, what's the issue? Looks like a rotated picture to me. Except the colours seem off. Is this really a red linksys, or did blue and red get swapped too?

Comment: @Jeffrey The issue is the picture is upside down, how would I fix it

Comment: IMHO, a better method is to convert the pixels into a matrix.  Apply transformation functions to the matrix, then convert matrix back to an image.  This allows you to apply rotational algorithms (for example, 20 degrees), scale and account for aspect ratios.  See also Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough, invert the rows, change

```
rotated[rotatedTarget.offset(col, row, chan)] =
    srcData[sourceImage.offset(row, col, chan)];
```

to

```
rotated[rotatedTarget.offset(rotatedTarget.mWidth-col-1, row, chan)] =
    srcData[sourceImage.offset(row, col, chan)];
```

Something like that anyway. I'm a bit confused about your code.

Comment: it's flipped. but as you see in the edited post, it's 0,0 is offseted down, please tell me how would I fix it

Comment: @andreahmed I don't know, that's probably a problem with how you are displaying the image, not how you are rotating it.